# how to roll back from main branch in Development and Release Isolation Branching in TFS

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs, branching-and-merging

My branching strategy involves

- Main Branch (latest stable code not in prod yet)
- Dev Branch (non stable code being developed in parallel)

  - Dev Branch 1
  - Dev Branch 2
- Release Branch

  - V 1.00 (code already in prod)

The code in Dev Branch 1 is always merged into Main branch, as It will be the next code to deploy in production. And also because is the way to merge it back to the parallel Dev Branch 2.

Imagine in some point, the business decides some of the features (many different checkins) in Dev Branch 1 won't be required (they are already merged in main, also in different daily merges), and decided to remove them for the next prod deployment.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

1. Create a new Dev Branch 3, to remove the code and merge it back to Main (and then to the other dev branches)
2. Remove the code directly from Main Branch, checkin in new modified code
3. Perform roll back of many changeset in main branch, in order to remove the not needed code
4. other?

From my current experience all of them are painful, thats why I need betters suggestions

Thanks

Comment: ""some of the features" Does these cover ALL of the changesets in Main since a particular point and time?  Or is it mixed in with stuff you want to keep?  I think you can branch from a specific point in time(in case you didn't have a label on the previous version)? You can branch from main at the point in time that you want to "restore", and so now Main has two branches from that point in time.  The stuff you don't want is the old branch, and the new branch is now absent that stuff.  So you simply ignore the old branch and continue work on the new "main" branch.

Comment: The case is a mixed stuff I want to remove from main branch. Understand  your point but removing all from specific point of time is not possible.